# Edit / Update dependent dropdows in dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, eloquent, drop-down-menu

I want to edit an invoice, which contains products (dynamically added fields with 3 dynamic dropdowns).
So, the idea is I want to show the old products of the invoice with the possibility to add new ones.
But I don't know how to get the old values of the dynamic dropdowns.
I did it only with categories because it's in the blade, but the problem is when I create a new product, i get the same category as the previous one.

[image]

edit_invoice blade

```
<tbody class="addMoreProduct">

                                        @foreach ($invoices->details as $item)
                                     
                                       
                                        <tr id="{{$loop->index}}">
                                          
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="categorie_id[{{ $loop->index }}]" id="categorie_id"
                                                    class="form-control categorie_id ">
                                                    <option label="Choisir Categorie"></option>
                                                    @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                                                        <option  value="{{ $categorie->id }}"
                                                            {{ $item->categorie_id == $categorie->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                                            {{ $categorie->categorie_name }}
                                                        </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                           
                                           </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td> <select name="product_id[{{ $loop->index }}]" id="categorie_id"
                                                    class="form-control product_id ">
                                                    <option label="Choisir Produit"></option>
     
                                                </select></td>
                                            <td> <select name="size_id[{{ $loop->index }}]" id="size_id" class="form-control size_id ">

                                                    <option label="Choisir Designation"></option>

                                                </select></td>



                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" name="quantity[{{ $loop->index }}]" class="form-control quantity"  value="{{ old('quantity', $item->quantity) }}"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="unit_price[0]"
                                                    class="form-control unit_price " value="{{ old('unit_price', $item->unit_price) }}"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" name="total_price[{{ $loop->index }}]"
                                                    class="form-control total_price" value="{{ old('total_price', $item->total_price) }}" readonly  />
                                            </td>
                                            <td> 
                                                 @if ($loop->index == 0)
                                                {{'#'}}
                                                @else
                                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                                @endif
                                              </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        @php
                            $i=$loop->index;
                            @endphp
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
```

Invoices controller: Update

```
 public function update(Request $request, invoices $invoices)
{
    $invoices = invoices::findOrFail($request->invoice_id);

    $data['invoice_no'] = $request->invoice_no;
    $data['last_invoice_no'] = $request->last_invoice_no;
    $data['devise'] = $request->devise;
    $data['customer_name'] = $request->customer_name;
    $data['customer_adress'] = $request->customer_adress;
    $data['invoice_no'] = $request->invoice_no;
    $data['invoice_date'] = $request->invoice_date;
    $data['company_adress'] = $request->company_adress;
    $data['company_name'] = $request->company_name;
    $data['company_phone'] = $request->company_phone;
    $data['poids_brut'] = $request->poids_brut;
    $data['poids_net'] = $request->poids_net;
    $data['livraison'] = $request->livraison;
    $data['incoterm'] = $request->incoterm;
    $data['payment_details'] = $request->payment_details;
    $data['sub_total'] = $request->sub_total;
    $data['shipping'] = $request->shipping;
    $data['total_due'] = $request->total_due;
    $data['created_by'] = (Auth::user()->name);

    $invoice = Invoices::create($data);

    $details_list = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->categorie_id); $i++) {
        $details_list[$i]['categorie_id'] = $request->categorie_id[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['product_id'] = $request->product_id[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['size_id'] = $request->size_id[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['quantity'] = $request->quantity[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['unit_price'] = $request->unit_price[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['total_price'] = $request->total_price[$i];
        $details_list[$i]['created_by'] = (Auth::user()->name);
    }

    $details = $invoice->details()->createMany($details_list);

    if ($details) {
        return redirect()->back()->with([
            'message' => __('la facture est créé avec succès'),
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with([
            'message' => __('la creation de facture a échoué'),
            'alert-type' => 'danger'
        ]);
    }
}
```

jQuery :

```
**script responsible for adding new fields :** 

 var i = '<?php echo $i; ?>';

    $('.add_more').on('click', function() {

        ++i;
        var categorie = $('.categorie_id').html();
    
        var tr = '<tr>' +
            '<td> <select class="form-control categorie_id  "  id="categorie_id" name="categorie_id[' + i +
            ']" >' + categorie +
            '</select></td>' +
            '<td>  <select class="form-control product_id  "  id=product_id" name="product_id[' + i +
            ']" ><option label="Choisir Produit"></option></select></td>' +
            '<td>  <select class="form-control size_id  "  id="size_id" name="size_id[' + i +
            ']" ><option label="Choisir Designation"></option></select></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text" name="quantity[' + i + ']" class="form-control quantity" ></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text" name="unit_price[' + i + ']" class="form-control unit_price" ></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text" name="total_price[' + i +
            ']" class="form-control total_price" readonly></td>' +
            '<td> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete "><i class="fa fa-trash"></a></td></tr>';


        $('.addMoreProduct').append(tr);


    });
    $('.addMoreProduct').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

**Script responsible for generating the products and sizes (Dynamic dropdowns)**

```
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name^="categorie_id"]', function() {
        var curEle = jQuery(this);
        var categorieID = curEle.val();
        var parentEle = curEle.closest('tr');
        var prodEle = parentEle.find('select[name^="product_id"]');
        var sizeEle = parentEle.find('select[name^="size_id"]');
        sizeEle.empty();
        prodEle.empty();

        if (categorieID) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/getProducts/' + categorieID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    prodEle.append(' <option label="Choisir Produit"></option>');
                    sizeEle.append(' <option label="Choisir Designation"></option>');
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        prodEle.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +
                            '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

 $(document).on('change', 'select[name^="product_id"]', function() {
        var cur = jQuery(this);
        var productID = cur.val();
        var parent = cur.closest('tr');

        var sizeEle = parent.find('select[name^="size_id"]');
        sizeEle.empty();


        if (productID) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/getDesignation/' + productID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    sizeEle.append(' <option label="Choisir Designation"></option>');
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        sizeEle.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +
                            '</option>');

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try commenting out `prodEle.empty();`. That removes the originals before you do the append in ajax

Comment: not working ,  it removes the old value when you change the category to show the products related to the selected category

Comment: This would be a lot easier to help with if you provided an html example that doesn't include php code. Then we could actually run it in the browser and see the issue. Just one sample row would probably be all that is needed along with the jQuery and a simple example of ajax response data. See [mcve]

Comment: HI, can you explain in short what exactly not working ?

Comment: when I want to edit, the old values of the selected items not showing up

Comment: where is code for edit ? @SaraTabbassi